# WinForms checkbox list value changed or selected index changed not responding quickly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a CheckedListBox with the following events

`checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged`

But when I am quickly performing the operation the group controls enabling is not working that quickly, I mean to say enabling and disabling is not performing that faster.

This is my event

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            groupBox1.Enabled = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex);
        if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            groupBox2.Enabled = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1);
    }
```

This is how it looks when I run the form

[image]

When I am quickly navigating this is how it looks

[image]

Comment: Is this code in both events? You could be seeing recursive behaviour which takes a while to finish

Comment: So is there any way to overcome

Comment: Only use one of the events- no need to use both

Comment: I am using only one event but still the same `chkList_SelectedValueChanged`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show full code in winform, we need a [mcve]

Comment: `chkList_SelectedValueChanged` is just the `EventHandler`, it not the same as the `event`

Comment: So which I event I need to handle

Answer (score 0):

Just use `chkList_SelectedValueChanged` and remove the SelectedIndexChange EventHandler.

Please do some tutorials on debugging, you will not get good until you can diagnose problems like this yourself.

*"While we can feed you fish for a day, it is better that you learn how to fish, to feed yourself for life."*

Comment: I am using only `chkList_SelectedValueChanged ` but still the behavior is same